# Child div with position: absolute not acting as a nested child

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on something in React, and I have something like this:

```
 <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
   <input />
   <div style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The child div needs to be absolute so that it overlaps a parent div. The only problem I'm having is that I want onBlur to trigger when this parent div loses focus, but since my child has position: 'absolute' and basically 'floats' above the parent, it doesn't have focus when the parent div does.

Comment: "The child div needs to be absolute so that it overlaps a parent div", why it needs to be absolute?

Comment: @DennisVash This small segment of code is part of a much bigger structure. I need it to be absolute for it to overlap other content.

Comment: can you give us the more complete code, or perhaps a working codepen or jsfiddle?  It may be something you can do in your actual onBlur event.

Comment: you can't do that. If the containing parent has a position: relative, any absolutely positioned children will be absolutely positioned with respect to that parent. Render that div outside of the div with position: relative.